# unable to find the error in the following method in java

Tags: java, class, methods, arraylist

I am a writing a method inside my class called ArrayIntList. This class has two fields, an array of int and int size which indicates the length of array. I am ignoring the constructor here and directly going to the method that I have issues. The method I am trying to write is longestSortedSequence which would return int type of longest sequence of sorted integers in the list. for example, this would return

```
[1, 3, 5, 2, 9, 7, -3, 0, 42, 308, 17] ---> 4,
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 19, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]----> 6
```

The code below works for the first case but fails in second case and I am unable to understand why.

```
public class ArrayIntList {
    private int[] elementData;
    private int size;



public int longestSortedSequence() {
    //this stores the longest sequence possible
    int max_count=0;
    //this stores the counts till not sorted sequence is encountered
    // and is flushed to zero before the next counting begins
    int count=0;
    int i=0;
    while(i<size-1) {
        if (elementData[i]<=elementData[i+1]){
            count++;
        }
        else {
            max_count=Math.max(max_count,count+1);
            count=0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return max_count;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated?
Thanks

Comment: Does it throw any exceptions? Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: By "fails" I think you mean "gives the wrong answer," right? If you expected answer is 6, what answer does it give instead?

Comment: no exceptions is thrown. As I mentioned above, the code gives the exepected output for the firstcase but produces wrong output (4 instead of 6) for the second case. I guess I am missing some logistics but uable to figure out what

Comment: Also, use a *[for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)* instead of the while loop.

Comment: It did not make any difference using for loop and while loop, I tried both

Comment: Are you sure you're actually running the 2nd case and not just running the 1st case twice? Also, I know the `while` loop works fine—it's just weird since this is exactly what `for` loops are for.

Comment: I have a bunch of test cases, it passed all of them except this. that is why I am posting here.

Comment: can you step through with a debugger?

Comment: I suggest that you fire up a debugger or add System.out.println() calls to your code to find out what it is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed code piece :

```
    while(i<size-1) {
            if (elementData[i]<=elementData[i+1]){
                count++;
            }
            else {
                max_count=Math.max(max_count,count+1);
                count=0;
            }
            i++;
        }
// added following 1 line.
    max_count=Math.max(max_count,count+1);
        return max_count;
```

Answer (score 2):

You only assign `max_count` if you detect an end of the sequence (the `else` branch).

If your second example, the longest sequence is at the end (6), but your code never has a chance to assign to `max_count`.

Move the assignment to `max_count` out of the `else`.  Then your `if` will have run already also, so `count` will have been incremented already, and there will be no need to add `1` to `count` when comparing to `max_count`.

Comment: If the assignment is moved out of else loop and into the while loop, you will unnecessarily end up doing assignment of max_count every single time. The solution I posted eliminates this.